# get more element attribute costum

Tags: jquery

Code :

```
<div id="gallery" data-image="img_folder/g1.jpg"></div>
<div id="gallery" data-image="img_folder/g2.jpg"></div>
<div id="gallery" data-image="img_folder/g3.jpg"></div>
<div id="gallery" data-image="img_folder/g4.jpg"></div>
<div id="gallery" data-image="img_folder/g5.jpg"></div>
```

CSS :

```
<style type="text/css">
#gallery { width:100px; height:100px; background-size:cover; }
</style>
```

jquery :

```
var el = $("#gallery");
var img = el.attr("data-image");

for(i=0; i<=el.length; i++) {
    el.css({ "backgroundImage": "url("+img+")" });
}
```

but, image not display to div, without success any idea ???

Comment: ID's should be unique...

Comment: Even if `el` contained multiple elements, note that `.attr`: *"get(s) the value of an attribute for the **first element** in the set of matched elements [...]."* (http://api.jquery.com/attr/) Reading documentation really helps, you should give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

First ID of an element must be unique,use class

```
<div class="gallery" data-image="img_folder/g1.jpg"></div>
<div class="gallery" data-image="img_folder/g2.jpg"></div>
<div class="gallery" data-image="img_folder/g3.jpg"></div>
<div class="gallery" data-image="img_folder/g4.jpg"></div>
<div class="gallery" data-image="img_folder/g5.jpg"></div>
```

and

```
.gallery { width:100px; height:100px; background-size:cover; }
```

then

```
$('.gallery').css('backgroundImage', function(){
    return 'url(' + $(this).data('image') + ')';
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ySX36/)